# Deny access to a file

Tags: php, .htaccess

If I drop a .ini file inside my site root directory, it will be visible to anyone simply by accessing

`http://site.com/file.ini`

Can I restrict public access to that file somehow (htaccess maybe?), but still make it accessible by my scripts?

Comment: Why don't you just keep that file outside of the document root?

Comment: I second the suggestion of placing outside your doc root. That is a great move for lots of sensitive files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this to your .htaccess file:

```
<files file.ini>
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
</files>
```

Check out the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#files).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this kind of security, if you don't want people to be able to directly access your web-scripts, is to put those files outside of the web-directory/web-root. That way the files within your website can still access the files via the file-paths, but people can't navigate to them with their browsers.

For example: my own private scripts reside in the 'private' folder, which is in the same directory as the `/var/www/` directory, and are accessed via: `include '../private/script.php';`

Answer (score 1):

You could simply move that file or add this to your .htaccess:

```
<Files ~ "\.(ini)$">
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
</Files>
```